# how to clear the fields in the login page while refreshing in asp.net master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one login page that inherits master page. I enter the incorrect username and password then clicking the login button it will shows the error message. I want when I refreshing the page both error message and username field will remove. Can anyone have this experience.. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")` method.